# C++ unable to use enum and switch together

Tags: c++, enums, switch-statement

From what I've seen, I should be able to run a switch on a enum, but mine is spitting back errors:

```
enum EMETH {TRAP=1, SIMP=2, MIDP=3, SINF=4};



switch(METH)
{
    case "TRAP":
        Meth=&Integrators::Trap;
        break;
    case "SIMP":
        Meth=&Integrators::Simp;
        break;
    case "MIDP":
        Meth=&Integrators::Midp;
        break;
    case "SINF":
        Meth=&Integrators::SInf;
        break;
}
```

The errors are

```
 error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
       case "TRAP":
 error: ‘(int)((long int)"TRAP")’ is not a constant expression
```

for each case.

Comment: What is `METH`, since you don't show it? And if you want to use enums, why put strings in the cases (side note, you can't `switch` on a string in C++)?

Comment: As others have said, you shouldn't put double quotes around your enumeration identifiers in the cases.  Separately, you shouldn't use all-uppercase identifiers for enumerations - they're liable to conflict with #defines in C headers, especially with names like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By putting quotes around the names of the enum members, you've made them string constants.  Thus the error that you're doing an invalid conversion.  Switch statements operate on ordinals, which is what enum members are.  So remove the ""s.

```
enum EMETH {TRAP=1, SIMP=2, MIDP=3, SINF=4};

switch(METH)
{
    case TRAP:
        Meth=&Integrators::Trap;
        break;
    case SIMP:
        Meth=&Integrators::Simp;
        break;
    case MIDP:
        Meth=&Integrators::Midp;
        break;
    case SINF:
        Meth=&Integrators::SInf;
        break;
}
```